# Phoenix generator errors on windows. "Permission Denied"

Tags: windows, permissions, elixir, phoenix-framework, tar

I'm trying to start with Elixr/Phoenix, so I followed some tutorials. Installed Erlang and Elixir, and then the Phoenix Framework. But I cant build the projects whatsoever

When typing  $ mix phx.new abc to start a project it fails in the very last item

- creating abc/assets/js/app.js
- creating abc/priv/static/robots.txt
  ** **(File.Error) could not write to file "c:/Users/Hippo/Desktop/programa├º├úo/elixir test/abc

Also, when trying to install all the dependencies with *mix deps.get* is just dont work:

**(Mix) Unpacking tarball failed: inner tarball error, permission denied**

How can i fix this? Going back to a older version could work? if so how I do this?

Comment: Just in case, try it from a folder with a simpler name than `programa├º├úo/elixir test/`. Without non-English characters and spaces.

Comment: changed "programa├º├úo" to just "programa" and tried the same in a folder called "a" and nothing changes unfortunately